# Performance of symmetric sparse matrix of dimension 5 000 000: Save to Database or File?

Tags: python, database, file, sparse-matrix

I have a huge dataset (around 5 000 000 rows in a database) which I want to represent as a graph. For algorithmic reasons it is required to store the dataset in a adjacency matrix. The Matrix will be **very sparse and symmmetric**.

First I thought of storing the graph in a database table. This would require 5 000 000 rows, which should be no problem. But 5 000 000 columns? I don't know much of databases but I have the feeling, that this would be no recommended way of doing this.

After some searching within google, I found SciPy which has several Sparse Matrix Objects. lil_matrix and coo_matrix seem to be what I need.

Since I will operate on this matrix using python, SciPy seems a good why to go. The question for me now is how to store the graph aka sparse matrix?

Should I use a csv file? Should I use coo_matrix to save the matrix into a daatabase_table? Both would result into around 2 500 000 000 000 rows/lines

Or is there a far better way for creating and storing such a symmetric and sparse "Matrix" of dimension around 5 000 000 in python?

I am using numpy and some self written algorithms in python, which I want to run on the matrix. So it would be cool, if the suggestions make it easy to use python on the graph.

I don't know if I provided enough information for an answer. If you need more information: Feel free to ask me in a comment or so. I will gladly edit my answer.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the numpy sparse matrix format. But all of your questions depend on the number of non-zero entries (NNZ) in the matrix. Storage and lots of computations are dependent (approximately) only on the NNZ. [Start here](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Sparse).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a dict to represent the matrix, which you can wrap in a class if you need a simple access.

```
class SymmetricSparseMatrix:
    def __init__(self, nlines, ncols):
        self.nlines = nlines
        self.ncols = ncols
        self._dict = {}

    def _check_coords(self, coords):
        """check coordinate range, and permutate i and j if necessary to 
        take advantage of the symmety of the matrix"""
        i, j = coords
        if not(0 <= i < self.nlines) or not(0 <= j < self.ncols):
            raise ValueError(coords)
        if i > j:
            return j, i
        else:
            return coords

    def __setitem__(self, coords, val):
        coords = self._check_coords(coords)
        self._dict[coords] = val
        if val == 0:
            del self._dict[coords]

    def __getitem__(self, coords):
        coords = self._check_coords(coords)
        return self._dict.get(coords, 0)
```

This is very close to scipy's `dok_matrix` core implementation, with additional processing ton only store half the values.